# How to add CSS to struts2 tags

Tags: java, css, struts2, tags

I am using struts2 to build a web application and I use struts2 tags extensively. I am not able to apply `CSS` styles to my struts2 `textfields`, `buttons`, `labels` etc. What is the trick for setting `CSS` rules to struts2 UI components.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The struts2 tags have two attributes that are used for this, the cssClass and the cssStyle attributes. The cssClass attribute takes the name of a class that you create in your CSS file. The cssStyle attribute take a string representing CSS style. E.g.

```
 <s:checkbox cssClass="mycheckbox" label="checkbox test" name="checkboxField1" value="aBoolean" fieldValue="true"/>
```

and

```
  <style>
      .mycheckbox{
        /* Your style here */
      }

  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a struts2 form get its own class or id name. For example when the whole form gets converted into HTML table tag, the table tag gets a class name 'wwFormTable'. You can check the same in Firebug and apply css to those generated classes or ids.